# SignalR js Client 'access-token' not pass 401 error

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, signals, bearer-token, http-status-code-401

I have a js client with this  chat hub configuration :

```
//this is my jwt token
 let userAuthToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken").toString();
 hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/chathub", {  accessTokenFactory: () => userAuthToken })
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();
```

and i also use

> [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
> public class ChatHub : Hub
> {

> }

for my chatHub class
but I still get a 401 error and I can't connect to chathub with postman too.
note:

> I have a mobile app socket client that should connect to chathub with auth
> thanks for your help guys

Comment: How do you generate the token? Could you pls share more code?

Comment: I use microsoft jwtAuth Library to generate token  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
            {
                jwt.SaveToken = true;
                jwt.TokenValidationParameters = TokenValidationParams;
            });